# Nudity reticence in John Wick 2

Tags: directors, john-wick-chapter-2

*John Wick 2* is a solidly R-rated movie that delights in plastering the screen with gritty blood-and-guts. In a dramatically key scene featuring a very intentionally nude woman, every shot is awkwardly staged or edited to avoid actually showing any nudity above a PG level.  **Why?**

The casting script must have clearly indicated that the most significant scene for the role called for full nudity.

Is there a business reason to avoid bringing R-rated nudity into an R-rated blockbuster action movie?

Or is nudity known to be a hang-up with any individual with executive authority in this production?

Comment: It could be the film makers realized nudity was unessesary. As you said JW2 is more about blood and violence and less about sex or nudity. If they really wanted to, they could have filmed it differently, and not have her naked at all or even in another room. The first move had one of the character in a VIP room of a club and in a pool with women all around with women in swimsuits.

Comment: I didn't watch the movie, but maybe **she** didn't want to show everything.

Comment: @AnneDaunted I know that every actor draws some line on nudity and sex.  But the script called for exposed nudity on this character in the most substantial of her three scenes.  The role was amenable to a wide variety of actresses, so I would be surprised (but fascinated to learn if this does in fact happen) that after casting an actress could object to the scripted nudity.

Comment: @feetwet - She could object to it, but it's likely that they told her it won't be shown in the movie. As I said in my comment, I believe it's the filmmakers not wanting to go to far with sex and nudity.

Comment: @S.R. – Unnecessary, yes.  Except that they put the scene in the script, and the nudity was a big part of its (potential) impact, and they chose to shoot it and include it.  And the pains they took to avoid showing *any* nudity made the whole scene awkward and distant compared to the rest of the movie.  To the point that I can't even fathom a theory where it could stand as some sort of meta-commentary on depictions of violence vs nudity in film.  It was like they let a Disney director do a scene in the middle of a Tarantino movie.

Comment: I guess we'll never know unless you hear a DVD commentary or interview with the writers/directors. Some directors just want to depict an actress naked, but never actually show anything. The James Bond film series does it a lot. As I said above WIck could have  approached her in an entirely different room or situation, he just happened to do it while she was preparing for a bath. I understand what you're saying, given the R rating why not go all the way and show the nudity?, this is why I suggested the directors don't want to focus on it, i.e all you the viewer needs to know is she is naked.

Comment: @feetwet - If the actress had a problem, highly doubt she would have taken her clothes off even if the viewer doesn't see everything. I think she was fine with it, but the film makers decided not to go further with it. For me, it was fine, I didn't go into JW2 to see nudity, I went for the violence.

Comment: @feetwet - If you have an actress who does a great job with acting the role, you aren't going to cast her aside for a less skilled actress who is willing to show her naughty bits.  Well, maybe one would, if one didn't care too much about the quality of the film. In any case, a body double would be an obvious choice if the nudity was a non-starter.  Possibly there was so much blood and violence that nudity, in addition, would have pushed it to NC-17?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet it was very uncharged nudity; not really sexualized in any way, so I don't think rating was a consideration.  Also, it appears likely from the film that the actress did in fact perform the scene completely nude, and they just shot and edited the scene to obscure her.  (There's even a full-frontal shot that looks like it may have been blurred and obscured *in post-production*!)

Comment: In that case, it does seem to be a bit of a mystery, so +1.

Comment: The character is metaphorically "naked" before a killer - naked in the sense of _vulnerable._ Any graphic nudity satisfying voyeuristic desires would have simply been gratuitous, especially as the character is committing suicide and being murdered. As written, this question, however, is merely soliciting opinion and should be closed or reworded to solicit knowledge claims.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy: The question is soliciting factual information, not opinion.  There is no question that an answer meeting SE criteria exists.  The fact that it has not yet been found, and may not yet have been articulated or communicated by people who know the answer does not mean it does not exist.  E.g., "The producer and/or director and/or actress has said *X* with respect to this question."

Comment: Unfocused conjectures do not help your post. if you are looking for information regarding MPAA rating calculus, ask about that. If you are asking about patterns of executive decision making from the administrative staff from this movie, ask about that, otherwise your **"Why?"** is merely soliciting opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of all of the above. Overall, sex or romance is clearly not part of the story, so showing a nude becomes gratuitous.

It does depend a lot on the story. If it has a host of questionable characters, such as a Jim Thompson book or perhaps Hubert Selby Jr.'s "Last Exit To Brooklyn", things such as nudity or physical sex are more likely to be accepted.

In general, the Puritanical attitude still has a grip of sorts in U.S. culture, and this shows up in the mainstream media. That's why there's no issue with violence, but when it comes to physical intimacy, you're starting to tread in murky territory.